# How can I disable apache2 error logging?

Tags: apache2

In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I have uncommented the following line:

`# ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`

Which resulted in the following:

```
serv:/var/log/apache2# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Restarting web server: apache2 ... waiting (2)No such file or directory: apache2: could not open error log file /etc/apache2/logs/error_log.
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

How can I disable error logging of virtual hosts that contain no ErrorLog/CustomLog directive?

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://serverfault.com

Comment: Simply `touch /etc/apache2/logs/error_log` and you should be fine. Why did you uncomment the ErrorLog directive in apache.conf in the first place if you don't want the logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see apache can not open log file. In this case you must change

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

with

```
/etc/apache2/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

This resolution it can be see in [stating apache ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639623).

Answer (score 0):

Try starting apache using the following command

```
service apache2 start
```